# How to communicate between a windows service and a desktop application running on different machines

Tags: c#, wcf, push-notification, windows-services, signalr

I am writing a notification client desktop application to be installed on multiple machines on a single network.  These clients will communicate with a central windows service running on a single machine within the same network.  Both the client and service are written in C#.Net.  I am trying to determine what technologies or frameworks I should use for communication between the client apps and the windows service.  I hope to use a push notification pattern instead of polling from the client.

So far I have looked into SignalR and WCF.  WCF with NamedPipes looked promising, but I saw that a limitation of the WCF NamedPipes implementation is that it has to be on the same machine, so that won't work for me.  SignalR seems like a good option, but I wasn't sure if there is another framework out there that won't require hosting a web server to support HTTP.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: You could use WCF with TCP transport and duplex services. Depending on what other quality attributes your solution requires, like authentication, encryption, guaranteed delivery, you can add these additional functionalities to the communication stack. Clients will establish the underlying TCP connection with the server-side service and from that point on the server can "push" notifications to the client by calling a method on the client-side service object.

Comment: You can selfhost SignalR as described here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host in which case you will not have to run IIS or anything like that.

Comment: @Pawel - I think I'm going to give self-hosted SignalR a try.  I still requires a web server, but I can self-host with OWIN.  For now this seems to be my best/easiest option.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider MSMQ to send messages. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx

This framework does not require anything special, as it is included with Windows. You may need to install the MSMQ as a Windows Feature. In my use it has been a pretty good utility that allows notifications and a host of other features.

Comment: I looked into MSMQ and RabbitMQ and they do seem like viable options, but I'd rather not have to deal with installing additional Windows features or an additional Windows service on the server machine and/or client machine because queuing frameworks can't be self-hosted.